# Reading/Displaying information from an XML File On Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to keep record of a persons name, score etc.

I get massive errors when I try to compile? Maybe I am just missing something but it looks right to me, please help. Thank you very much!

```
        private void scoreButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    try { 
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new File("scores.xml"));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("Root element of the doc is "+ doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList listOfPlayers = doc.getElementsByTagName("player");
        int totalPersons = listOfPlayers.getLength();
        System.out.println("Total number of people: "+ totalPersons);



    for (int s = 0; s<listOfPlayers.getLength(); s++) {
            Node firstPersonNode = listOfPlayers.item(s);
          if (firstPersonNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element firstPersonElement = (Element) firstPersonNode;
                NodeList firstNameList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("first");
                Element firstNameElement = (Element) firstNameList.item(0);
                NodeList textFNList = firstNameElement.getChildNodes();
                System.out.println("First Name: " + ((Node)textFNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                NodeList lastNameList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("last");
                Element lastNameElement = (Element)lastNameList.item(0);
                NodeList textLNList = lastNameElement.getChildNodes();
                System.out.println("Money: " + ((Node)textLNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                NodeList ageList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("age");
                Element ageElement = (Element)ageList.item(0);
                NodeList textAgeList = ageElement.getChildNodes();
                System.out.println("Age: " + ((Node)textAgeList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

            }
        } catch(SAXParseException err) {

    }
}
```

Here is the scores.xml file:

```
    <scores>

<player>
    <name> Sam Moeza </name>
    <money> 100 </money>
    <age> 22 </age>
</player>

<player>
    <name> Larry Hoover </name>
    <money> 100000 </money>
    <age> 55 </age>
</player>

    </scores>
```

Here is the error:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    at casinoroulette.CasinoRouletteView.scoreButtonActionPerformed(CasinoRouletteView.java:327)
    at casinoroulette.CasinoRouletteView.access$1200(CasinoRouletteView.java:24)
    at casinoroulette.CasinoRouletteView$8.actionPerformed(CasinoRouletteView.java:173)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: post the scores xml...

Comment: 1) Please post the "massive error" messages. 2) You should never have an empty catch block like you show above, not unless you also like driving your car with your eyes closed.

Comment: posted all information

Comment: The message is telling you *exactly* what's wrong. I'd read it critically, and fix what it's telling you to fix. You need to catch or throw the ParserConfigurationException at the site where the error is located. And again, you should not ignore your catch block. Please read the tutorial section on exceptions before trying to make more code. It will be time well spent.

Comment: Start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html).

Comment: Have you read the error message?

Comment: Also, you may want to study up on XPath, it will make you're life a lot easier ;)

Comment: Also, listen to what your compiler is telling you, because there is no way this code could have compiled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the obvious...

You're missing a closing `}` after the `if` or `for`...

```
try { 
    //...
    for (int s = 0; s<listOfPlayers.getLength(); s++) {
        Node firstPersonNode = listOfPlayers.item(s);
        if (firstPersonNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            //...
        //.. nothing here?
    }
} catch(SAXParseException err) {

}
```

Then move onto that fact that you'll need expand your `try-catch` to deal with `javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException` and `java.io.IOException`

For example...

```
try { 
    //...
    for (int s = 0; s<listOfPlayers.getLength(); s++) {
        Node firstPersonNode = listOfPlayers.item(s);
        if (firstPersonNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            //...
        } // Fix me
    }
} catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException ex) {
    // Don't forget to do something with your exception, like
    // log it or show and error message dialog
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you're using Java 7+ you can use the multi-catch demonstrated above, otherwise, you'll need to catch each one individually...

You might like to take some time reading through the [Exceptions trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) for more information